# How to Solved this Error, Failed connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

(node:9654) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?
Error details:
Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect

Comment: What version of node are you running?